# angular video source double slash interpolation error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have weird issue with angular template, available [here](http://jsbin.com/vepurixa/1/).

```
<div ng-init="src='//www'">
  {{src}}
  <video controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source ng-src="{{src}}" type="video/ogg" />
  </video>
</div>
```

When I'm trying to pass variable with double slash then it's not rendered inside `ng-src` for source element, but it works when it is used alone.

Anyone had this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In an Angular SPA, you should use `#` to link to the main page and `#/something` for the specific route.

Comment: but I want to set src to eg. movie file on external location,
it's not link to page

Comment: forgot to mention that,
then {{src}} isn't translated to value

Comment: `ng-init = "src = 'http//'+ {{controller_attr}} "` should work, followed by {{src}} should work. In any case, you should have the relevant string in the controller and use it in the HTML.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vepurixa/3/

jsbin updated to your proposition,
but no lack either :/
near video you can see changed string, 
but check source element in side video, 
it hasn't src tag at all

Answer (score 0):

ok, found it.

To be able to pass link to resource as a variable to angular's template,
you need to wrap url string using **$sce.trustAsResourceUrl** method.